# using acts_as votabable gem for likes and want to change the heart color to red permanently after user has liked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using the acts_as votable gem and I manage to change the heart color to red after a user has clicked on the heart by using javascript. However, once the server refreshes the heart goes gray again and there is no indication whether a user has liked the current post or not. How can I change the color permanently after a user has liked. My idea is to set a boolean to true in the vote table and then check that somehow in the view. But I am not sure how to implement it exactly. Any help would be much appreciated.

**lists_controller.rb**

```
def vote
 if !current_user.liked? @list
  @list.liked_by current_user
 elsif current_user.liked? @list
  @list.unliked_by current_user
end
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
<% if current_user.liked? @list %>
 $('.fa-heart').addClass('liked');
<% else %>
 $('.fa-heart').removeClass('liked');
 <% end %>
$('.likes-count').html("<%= @list.get_upvotes.size %>")
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="like">
   <%= link_to like_list_path(@list), :class => "like-btn", method: :put, remote: :true do %>
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#likeModalLong" do %>
        <span class="likes-count"><%= @list.get_upvotes.size %></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper to make the `liked` css class persistent in you view:

*application_helper*

```
def liked_list(list)
  liked = current_user.liked?(list) ? 'liked' : ''
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-heart #{liked}")
end
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to like_list_path(@list), :class => "like-btn", method: :put, remote: :true do %>
  <%= liked_list(@list) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you're so awesome!! thanks for the quick reply it worked perfectly